# Multiple skips in MSDeploy?

Tags: msdeploy

I'm aware of [the -skip parameter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089%28WS.10%29.aspx), but is there any way to tell MSDeploy to skip multiple directories? Invoking the parameter multiple times does not appear to work.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you have the following files in the folder `C:\Data\Personal\My Repo\MSDeploy\MultiSkip`.
[image]

To sync source to dest the command would be:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync 
    -source:contentPath="C:\Data\Personal\My Repo\MSDeploy\MultiSkip\Source" 
    -dest:contentPath="C:\Data\Personal\My Repo\MSDeploy\MultiSkip\Dest"
```

The changes are show in figure below.
[image]

With no skips there are 19 changes.

**Skip 1 folder**

Then the command to skip the sub03 directory would  be:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync 
    -source:contentPath="C:\Data\Personal\My Repo\MSDeploy\MultiSkip\Source" 
    -dest:contentPath="C:\Data\Personal\My Repo\MSDeploy\MultiSkip\Dest" 
    -skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath="sub03"
```

The result would be:

[image]

So there are 14 added files.

**Skip 2 directories**

To skip 2 directories the command would be

```
msdeploy -verb:sync 
    -source:contentPath="C:\Data\Personal\My Repo\MSDeploy\MultiSkip\Source" 
    -dest:contentPath="C:\Data\Personal\My Repo\MSDeploy\MultiSkip\Dest" 
    -skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath="sub03" 
    -skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath="sub02"
```

Then the result of that is
[image]
There are only 9 changes here so we can see that multiple skips does work.

Answer (score 6):

The `skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath=` accepts a regular expression, therefore you can achieve the same result as the answer above using:

```
-skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath="sub02|sub03"
```

The pipe `|` indicating `OR`