# Get MSDeploy to skip specific folders and file types in folders as CCNet task

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, msdeploy, ccnet-config

I want MSDeploy to [skip](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089%28WS.10%29.aspx) specific folders and file types within other folders when using sync. Currently I'm using CCNet to call MSDeploy with the sync verb to take websites from a build to a staging server. Because there are files on the destination that are created by the application / user uploaded files etc, I need to [exclude specific folders from being deleted on the destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088360/multiple-skips-in-msdeploy). Also there are manifest files created by the site that need to remain on the destination.

At the moment I've used `-enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule` but that leaves stale files on the destination.

```
<exec>
    <executable>$(MsDeploy)</executable>
    <baseDirectory>$(ProjectsDirectory)$(projectName)$(ProjectsWorkingDirectory)\Website\</baseDirectory>
    <buildArgs>-verb:sync 
        -source:iisApp="$(ProjectsDirectory)$(projectName)$(ProjectsWorkingDirectory)\Website\" 
        -dest:iisApp="$(website)/$(websiteFolder)"
        -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule</buildArgs>
    <buildTimeoutSeconds>600</buildTimeoutSeconds>
    <successExitCodes>0,1,2</successExitCodes>
</exec>
```

I have tried to use the skip operation but run into problems. Initially I dropped the DoNotDeleteRule and replaced it with (multiple) skip

```
<exec>
    <executable>$(MsDeploy)</executable
    <baseDirectory>$(ProjectsDirectory)$(projectName)$(ProjectsWorkingDirectory)\Website\</baseDirectory>
    <buildArgs>-verb:sync 
        -source:iisApp="$(ProjectsDirectory)$(projectName)$(ProjectsWorkingDirectory)\Website\" 
        -dest:iisApp="$(website)/$(websiteFolder)"
        -skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath="assets" 
        -skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath="survey" 
        -skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath="completion/custom/complete*.aspx" 
        -skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath="completion/custom/surveylist*.manifest" 
        -skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath="content/scorecardsupport" 
        -skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath="Desktop/docs" 
        -skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath="_TempImageFiles"</buildArgs>         
    <buildTimeoutSeconds>600</buildTimeoutSeconds>
    <successExitCodes>0,1,2</successExitCodes>
</exec>
```

But this results in the following:

> Error: Source (iisApp) and
>   destination (contentPath) are not compatible for the given
>   operation.
>   Error count:
>   1.

So I changed from iisApp to contentPath and instead of dirPath,absolutePath just Directory like this:

```
<exec>
    <executable>$(MsDeploy)</executable
    <baseDirectory>$(ProjectsDirectory)$(projectName)$(ProjectsWorkingDirectory)\Website\</baseDirectory>
    <buildArgs>-verb:sync 
        -source:contentPath="$(ProjectsDirectory)$(projectName)$(ProjectsWorkingDirectory)\Website\" 
        -dest:contentPath="$(website)/$(websiteFolder)"
        -skip:Directory="assets" 
        -skip:Directory="survey" 
        -skip:Directory="content/scorecardsupport" 
        -skip:Directory="Desktop/docs" 
        -skip:Directory="_TempImageFiles"</buildArgs>           
    <buildTimeoutSeconds>600</buildTimeoutSeconds>
    <successExitCodes>0,1,2</successExitCodes>
</exec>
```

and this gives me an error: Illegal characters in path:

> < buildresults>
>   Info: Adding MSDeploy.contentPath (MSDeploy.contentPath).
>   Info: Adding contentPath (C:\WWWRoot\MySite
>                -skip:Directory=assets
>                -skip:Directory=survey
>                -skip:Directory=content/scorecardsupport
>                -skip:Directory=Desktop/docs
>                -skip:Directory=_TempImageFiles).
>   Info: Adding dirPath (C:\WWWRoot\MySite
>                -skip:Directory=assets
>                -skip:Directory=survey
>                -skip:Directory=content/scorecardsupport
>                -skip:Directory=Desktop/docs
>                -skip:Directory=_TempImageFiles).
>   < /buildresults>
>
> < buildresults>
>     Error: Illegal characters in path.
>     Error count: 1.
>   < /buildresults>

So I need to know how to configure this task so the folders referenced do not have their contents deleted in a sync and that that *.manifest and *.aspx files in the completion/custom folders are also skipped.

Comment: Move that beast to a nant task and use nant <exec>. Debug it with Nantbuilder if need be. http://www.polestarsoft.com/products/nantbuilder/

Comment: There's a lot more in the ccnet project than that... can I mix and match nant and ccnet in that way, or would I have to convert the whole build script over to nant?

Comment: You can put as many tasks in the <tasks>, <prebuild> or <publisher> blocks as you'd like. For example: <tasks><exec>...</exec><nant>...</nant><exec>...</exec></tasks>. The tasks execute in the order they exist in the file. One thing I like a lot about Nant is its capacity to run C# script. http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.91/help/tasks/script.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue with this was... line breaks!
Where I'd split each -skip directive to a new line *that* was causing the illegal characters in path. Running all the skip directives inline has solved this:

```
<exec>
  <executable>$(MsDeploy)</executable>
  <baseDirectory>$(ProjectsDirectory)$(projectName)$(ProjectsWorkingDirectory)\Website\</baseDirectory>
  <buildArgs>-verb:sync 
            -source:contentPath="$(ProjectsDirectory)$(projectName)$(ProjectsWorkingDirectory)\Website\" 
            -dest:contentPath="C:\WWWRoot\$(websiteFolder)" -skip:Directory="assets" -skip:Directory="_TempImageFiles" -skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath="\\Desktop\\Docs"
  </buildArgs>          
  <buildTimeoutSeconds>600</buildTimeoutSeconds>
  <successExitCodes>0,1,2</successExitCodes>
</exec>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this MSDN article entitled [Web Deployment: Excluding Files and Folders via the Web Application’s Project File](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2010/04/22/web-deployment-excluding-files-and-folders-via-the-web-application-s-project-file.aspx).  Specifically the section "Excluding Specific Files / Folders".  This will stop directories, files, and file/dir pattern matches from both being included as content in the deployment package as well as ignored on the destination when deployed.

However, I would take a step back and ask why do these files exist in your web project in the first place.  The way I've handled user uploaded content on IIS is by adding a virtual directory to my web application.  The contents of virtual directories (and the provisioning of the vdir itself) is ignored when doing a sync on a web deploy package.  This also gives you the benefit of hosting the client content directory anywhere you like which has a whole score of advantages (i.e. bigger disk drive, prevention of denial of service by unscrupulous users who try to fill your hard disk with garbage data, etc.)