# Azure DevOps: How to maintain several tenants

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Looking for some advise regarding Azure DevOps release pipelines please.

I have a single repo with two ASP.NET web applications. The intention is use the release pipeline feature to manage deployments (from the master branch) to several tenants, all are self-hosted on IIS. Each tenant will host both web applications. The first web application has a tenant-specific web.config file and the second web application has a tenant-specific JavaScript file. It's easy to use [XML variable substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops#xmlvarsubs) for a single tenant (setting the build to "Release", for example) but I've got two challenges:

1. How can I maintain multiple web.config files within Azure DevOps depending on the release pipeline item / task?
2. How can I exclude the JavaScript file from the web deploy task?

For item 2, I used the -skip parameter as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46961055/6858167) but this isn't working. I'm assuming I have a syntax error but struggling to find a good resource that describes the -skip parameter.

```
-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath=\\app\\app\.js
```

[image: JavaScript file that needs excluding]

Thank you!

Comment: For item 2, I wrapped the absolutePath value in double quotes, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16431352/6858167) so the value is `-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath="\\app\\app\.js"` and is working now.